# How to remove everything from a string except for the number and put these in an array?

Tags: php, jquery, smarty

How to remove everything from a string except for the number and put these in an array?

```
["103","109","110"]
```

has to be a string with just the numbers.

I am using smarty and tried this.

```
{assign downloadCats $aMenu.aMenuvars.downloads|ltrim:'['|rtrim:']'}

{','|explode:$downloadCats}
{var_dump($downloadCats)}
```

Comment: please provide desire result

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions for this:

```
preg_match_all("/[0-9]+/", $input, $findings, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($findings as $value) {
  // do something with the value
}
```

For more infos or examples look here:
http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match-all.php